# How to append my json data into a selectlist?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api

There is a selectlist without any options in html.
I am going to get a list of names from API and I want to append them as options into my selectlist.

Here is the html code :

```
<div id="example" role="application">
<div class="demo-section k-header">
    <select id="FeaturesSelect" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select attendees...">
        
    </select>
</div>
```

And here is what I was trying for this solution but doesn't work.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var data = $.get("My API Address Here");
    $('#FeaturesSelect').empty();
    $.each(data,
        function(i, v) {
            $('#FeaturesSelect').append('<option value="' + v.id + '">' + v.title + '</option>');
        });
});
```

Here is the API example

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "James"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Robbert"
}
```

]

Comment: Put some example for API response.

Comment: I am able to render the data with the same code

Comment: @SuryaPrakashTumma you mean my code works for you ?

Comment: Yes  I am able to and I have mocked the data

Comment: @SuryaPrakashTumma how do you get the data from API and set them into a variable ?

Comment: I have mocked the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your code structure. Since your data is fetched through AJAX, your `.each` code won't have the data by the time it's executed. The solution is to place the loop logic in the jquery get success block.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#FeaturesSelect').empty();
    $.get("My API Address Here").done(function(data){
        $.each(data,
            function(i, v) {
                $('#FeaturesSelect').append('<option value="' + v.id + '">' + v.title + '</option>');
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in you code. I can see it's working fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = [{"id": "1","title": "James"},{"id": "2","title": "Robbert"}];
    $('#FeaturesSelect').empty();
    $.each(data,
        function(i, v) {
            $('#FeaturesSelect').append('<option value="' + v.id + '">' + v.title + '</option>');
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example" role="application">
<div class="demo-section k-header">
    <select id="FeaturesSelect" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select attendees...">
        
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This part of code doesn't work: var data = $.get("https://localhost/api/GetAllNames");

Answer (score 0):

Javascript asynchronous so your code is not waiting for the API response to come. so you need to use the promises to wait for the responses.

Please see the working code here

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    $('#FeaturesSelect').empty();
    $.each(data,
        function(i, v) {
            $('#FeaturesSelect').append('<option value="' + v.id + '">' + v.title + '</option>');
        });
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example" role="application">
<div class="demo-section k-header">
    <select id="FeaturesSelect" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select attendees...">
        
    </select>
</div>
```